# How can I update my user.image record in my firebase collection from a blob I uploaded to the firebase storage (React Native)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm successfully uploading the image to the firebase storage, but I can't get the URI to save in the user.image location.

EDIT - I am also getting a warning message "Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0): TypeError: uploadTask.on is not a function (it is undefined)

Here's the entire screen code minus trivial styling and unrelated stuff for brevity

```
import {db, auth, storage} from '../firebase';
import {onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth';
import { doc, getDoc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

const Account = ({navigation}) => {

  const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const docRef = doc(db, 'useraccounts', userId);

  const { userInfo, handleSignOut, deleteAccount } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    first: "",
    last: "",
    email: "",
    rank: "",
    dojo: "",
    image: "",
  });

  const getUser = () => {        
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if(user) {          
        user !== null || user !== undefined
        getDoc(docRef).then((docSnap) => {
          if (docSnap.exists()){
            setUser(docSnap.data());
          } else {
            console.log("nothing here"); 
          }      
        });
      } 
    }); 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  },[])



  // This is an event fired by a form button that handles other profile fields except the image, hence why the image update is not referenced here 
  const handleEdits = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    await updateDoc(docRef, {
        first: first || user.first,
        last: last || user.last,
        rank: rank || user.rank,
        dojo: dojo || user.dojo,
      }
    )
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Document successfully updated!");
      setIsLoading(false);
      setIsVisible(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
      setIsLoading(true);
    });
  
    
    getUser(); //refresh the user info
    
    //reset the form fields
    setFirst("");
    setLast("");
    setRank("");
    setDojo("");
  }

  const uploadImage = async (mode) => {
    try {
      let result = {};

      if (mode === "gallery") {
        await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
          allowsEditing: true,
          aspect: [1, 1],
          quality: 1,
        });
      } else {
        await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
        result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
          cameraType: ImagePicker.CameraType.front,
          allowsEditing: true,
          aspect: [1, 1],
          quality: 1,
        });
      }

      if (!result.canceled) {
        // save image
        await saveImage(result.assets[0].uri);
        
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert("Error uploading image: " + error.message);
      setModalVisible(false);
    }
  };

  const removeImage = async () => {
    try {
      saveImage(null);
    } catch ({ message }) {
      alert(message);
      setModalVisible(false);
    }
  };

  const saveImage = async (image) => {
    try {
      // update displayed image
      setImage(image);

      sendToBackend(image);

      setModalVisible(false);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };

  const sendToBackend = async (uri) => {

    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function(e) {
        console.error(e);
        reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
      };
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
      xhr.send(null);

    });

    const filename = new Date().getTime() + ".jpg";
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'profileimages/' + filename);
    // getDownloadURL(storageRef);


    const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, blob );
    
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
        switch (snapshot.state) {
          case 'paused':
            console.log('Upload is paused');
            break;
          case 'running':
            console.log('Upload is running');
            break;
        }
      }, 
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }, 
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
          console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
          updateDoc(docRef, {
            image: downloadURL,
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Document successfully updated!");
            getUser();
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
          });
        });
      }
    );

    blob.close();


  };
  
  return (
    ...
  )
}

export default Account
```

[image: In case you need a visual for what I need]

Comment: "*I can't get the URI to save in the user.image location.*" - What's the specific problem with this?  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I will point out unrelated that your getUser function doesn't return anything, but you're expecting that it does: `const unsubscribe = getUser()`

Comment: In order to show the image I need to read from the document's image location whihc should contain the URL from the storage. Then I can pass it to the UI to show the member's profile photo. I am able to save the image. But the document is not being updated with the URL for that image that was just uploaded

Comment: unsubscription removed, even though it has no effect on the problem I'm having

Comment: That's why I said "I will point out *unrelated*". Thought you might want to know of another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the uploadTask to

```
try {
  await uploadTask.then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
    getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref)
    .then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
      updateDoc(docRef, {
        image: downloadURL
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully updated!");
        getUser();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
      });
    });
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Basically, got rid of the progress bit and I'm updating the document's image location with the snapshot.ref which contains the URL for the image uploaded. Put it in a try catch to avoid crashes while it awaits.